# <body onload=foo()> doesn't call foo

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to run this code, but initialize() isn't called.

http://jsfiddle.net/r3sA8/

Can someone tell why ?

Comment: You can’t load an external script and embedded script with the same `script` element; you need to do that separately.

Comment: What code? There's no code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to creating a new `script` block as others have mentioned, you haven't ended your `initialize` function.

```
function initialize() {
            if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
                map.setCenter(new GLatLng(51.5, -0.1), 10);
                map.setUIToDefault();

                geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

                showAddressOnLoad("28 Gronemann Street, Tel Aviv, Israel");
            }
.
.
.
```

You should have another `}` to end your function. See [this updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3sA8/3/)

Answer (score 7):

Code within a `<script>` block is not evaluated when the tag has the `src` attribute set.

Replace the following:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyCP_o3czlByfGNa-S1YYMBAqfYKNg5nRKU&sensor=false"
    type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var geocoder;
    ...
```

with

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyCP_o3czlByfGNa-S1YYMBAqfYKNg5nRKU&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    var map;
    var geocoder;
    ...
```

(The `<script src="...">` tag is closed, and a new script block is started using `<script>`).

Comment: While this is generally true, you can make this syntax work if you really want; you can extract the script innerHTML inside the source file and use `eval()` on it: http://ejohn.org/blog/degrading-script-tags/

Comment: @David There's no need to confuse the OP. In Firefox' strict mode, `eval` does not evaluate in the context of the global namespace, so just `eval` will not work. In your linked source, jQuery's `globalEval` is used to parse the code. However, this does also make use of `eval`, which, as I said, does not work in Firefox. The technique can work when you create and insert a new `<script>` element. However, I recommend to not teach such tricks to beginners, and use separate `<script>` tags instead.

Comment: I agree, but I still wanted to point out that it can in fact exist and work just in case the OP had seen the syntax somewhere else and copied it. But I would never recommend it unless it was about a templating language or other meta-script variations.

Answer (score 2):

The error is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined.

If a `script` element has a `src` element, like in your example, its content is not evaluated by the browser.

The solution is to put the code in its own script tag:

```
<script src="..."></script>
<script>
    // your code here
</script>
```

---

Side note regarding jsFiddle: You should only put content which goes into the `body` in the HTML pane. And jsFiddle can certainly not evaluate special `asp` tags.